# How to avoid duplicate nodes when importing JSON into Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Let's say I have a JSON containing relationships between people:

```
{
    [
        {
            "name": "mike",
            "loves": ["karen", "david", "joy"],
            "loved": ["karen", "joy"]
        },
        {
            "name": "karen",
            "loves": ["mike", "david", "joy"],
            "loved": ["mike"]
        },
        {
            "name": "joy",
            "loves": ["karen"],
            "loved": ["karen", "david"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to import nodes and relationships into a Neo4J DB. For this sample, there's only one relationship ("LOVES") and the 2 lists each user has just control the arrow's direction. I use the following query to import the JSON:

```
UNWIND {json} as person
CREATE (p:Person {name: person.username})
FOREACH (l in person.loves | MERGE (v:Person {name: l}) CREATE (p)-[:LOVES]->(v))
FOREACH (f in person.loved | MERGE (v:Person {name: f}) CREATE (v)-[:LOVES]->(p))
```

My problem is that I now have duplicate nodes (i.e. 2 nodes with `{name: 'karen'}`). I know I could probably use `UNIQUE` if I insert records one at a time. But what should I use here when importing a large JSON? (to be clear: the name property would always be unique in the JSON - i.e., there are no 2 "mikes").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

Since you cannot assume that a `Person` node does not yet exist, you need to `MERGE` your `Person` nodes everywhere.

If there is no need to use your `loved` data (that is, if the `loves` data is sufficient to create all the necessary relationships):

```
UNWIND {json} as person
MERGE (p:Person {name: person.name})
FOREACH (l in person.loves | MERGE (v:Person {name: l}) CREATE (p)-[:LOVES]->(v))
```

On the other hand, if the `loved` data is needed, then you need to use `MERGE` when creating the relationships as well (since any relationship might already exist).

```
UNWIND {json} as person
MERGE (p:Person {name: person.name})
FOREACH (l in person.loves | MERGE (v:Person {name: l}) MERGE (p)-[:LOVES]->(v))
FOREACH (f in person.loved | MERGE (v:Person {name: f}) MERGE (v)-[:LOVES]->(p))
```

In both cases, you should create an index (or uniqueness constraint) on `:Person(name)` to speed up the query.

Comment: The assumption is wrong. there could be a case of someone who "loves" someone else, but is not "loved" by them. This is not a commutative relationship. So I do need both lists. Will merge work here?

Comment: But if karen "loved" mike, shouldn't the person data for karen have mike in its "loves" list? Or are you saying that the input array does not have an object for every person (like "david")? In any case, if you need to support the "loved" list as well, then you should use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` for the relationships.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed! And I also appreciate the index comment :)